# Python: how to remove repeat same items in the list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have  a list and want delete  repeat same items.

`list1 = [ 10-31, 19-45, 19-45, 64-01, 10-31, 19-45, 16-17 ]`

And try get this:

`list2 = [ 10-31, 19-45, 64-01, 10-31, 19-45,16-17]`

I already looked `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data1))` - method, but that's not what I want.

Comment: You mean you want to remove duplicates, or remove duplicates only if they are one-after-another?

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = ['10-31', '19-45', '19-45', '64-01', '10-31', '19-45', '16-17']
list2 = [x[0] for x in groupby(list1)]
list2
#['10-31', '19-45', '64-01', '10-31', '19-45', '16-17']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list2 = list(set(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to do this:

```
list1 = [ 10-31, 19-45, 19-45, 64-1, 10-31, 19-45, 16-17 ]
list2 = [ 10-31, 19-45, 64-2, 10-31, 19-45,16-17]
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
set3 = set1 | set2
```